# How to know to which package a particular function belongs to in R prior to package loading?

Tags: r, package

Example, I know many popular functions, to name one like `tbl_df()`. I usually do not remember which package it belongs to i.e. `data.table` or `dplyr`. So I have to always remember and load a package and I can not do `?tbl_df` unless I have loaded the correct package.

Is there a way to know to which package a particular function belongs to, prior to loading or installing of the package in R console itself.

Any help is highly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: have you used `??tbl_df`. There is a list of packages presented.

Comment: One optiion is `library(sos);findFn("tbl_df")`

Comment: @J_F that doesn't work for me.

Comment: @akrun Thats new, no clue about it, but it kinds of takes time to run. I am working on windows machine.

Comment: @J_F This looks good. Let me check some more info on that.

Comment: You can try searching using http://rseek.org - its faster than ?? because you have the power of the google servers working for you

Comment: @dww Thank you for this information, I'll check `rseek.org` I have heard of it, but never got a chance to look. :)

Answer (score 3):

sos package can help!
Try:

```
install.packages("sos")
library(sos)
findFn("str_replace")
```

Try this as well

```
lsp <- function(package, all.names = FALSE, pattern) 
{ package <- deparse(substitute(package)) ls( pos = paste("package", package, sep = ":"),
all.names = all.names, pattern = pattern ) }
```

after running this function, if you want to search for str_replace function in stringr package- lsp(stringr, pattern="*replace")

Comment: Try this as well-
lsp <- function(package, all.names = FALSE, pattern) 
{
  package <- deparse(substitute(package))
  ls(
    pos = paste("package", package, sep = ":"), 
    all.names = all.names, 
    pattern = pattern
  )
}

after running this function, if you want to search for str_replace function in stringr package-

lsp(stringr, pattern="*replace")

Comment: it's a bit intimidating as it's still a big string search and can return many hits... but you can sort the resulting HTML table by clicking any of the headers, including to sort by Function name and then quickly see those options.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by @J_F who suggested ??tbl_df: I was looking for 'arima' and had dozens if not hundreds of hits; I narrowed them down using

```
help.search('arima', fields=c('name'), ignore.case=FALSE, agrep=FALSE)
```

(most importantly, agrep=FALSE turns off fuzzy matching)

Answer (score 0):

Try highlighting the function then click the "fn + F1" buttons on your keyboard.

This works when packages are **installed already and not loaded**, but won't work if the packages aren't installed yet.

This way you don't have to type any more code, super easy!

Comment: What's supposed to happen after pressing  `fn + F1`?